# Django PositiveIntegerField accepting Negatives

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with a PositiveIntegerField in my Django application *(views)*:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', through="PostTagging", null=False, blank=False)
    rating = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

However, when I test it, it accepts negative values:

Test:

```
def test_post_with_negative_views(self):
    test_user = User.objects.get(username='test_student')
    test_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=test_user)

    post = Post.objects.create(author=test_user_profile, title='Django Testing', content='hello world', views=-10)
    self.assertEquals(post.views, 0)
```

Fail:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default' ...
......F.......
=====================================================================
FAIL: test_post_with_negative_views (bark.tets.PostTest)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ewan/Documents/WAD2/studeso/bark/bark/tests.py", line 58, in test_post_with_negative_views
    self.assertEquals(post.views, 0)
AssertionError: -10 != 0

---------------------------------------------------------------------

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

I've tried testing it with int(-10) and int("-10") incase it was a string formatting error I get a lot.

catavaran's answer including:

```
post.full_clean()
```

also fails.

Comment: Checking of positivity is done on database level and SQLite engine doesn't check it at all. It was changed in 1.7 release, which version of django are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the excerpt from the [validating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) chapter of the docs:

> Note that `full_clean()` will **not be called automatically** when you call your model’s `save()` method. You’ll need to call it manually when you want to run one-step model validation for your own manually created models.

So validating and saving model should look like this:

```
post = Post(author=test_user_profile, title='Django Testing',
            content='hello world', views=-10)
post.full_clean()
post.save()
```

**UPDATE**: Seems like this validation is turned off for SQLite backend.  I found this code in the `django.db.backends.sqlite3.operations.DatabaseOperations` class.

```
def integer_field_range(self, internal_type):
    # SQLite doesn't enforce any integer constraints
    return (None, None)
```

Values from this method are used to build validators for `PositiveIntegerField`.

As far as I understand this is done for compatibility reasons.  So if you want to work with SQLite then you have to manually add the validator:

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,
                                        validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
```

After this modification the `full_clean()` should work as expected.

Comment: The model is still accepting negatives using the above snippet.

Comment: Using `full_clean()` , `clean()` or `clean_fields()` doesn't throw any exceptions and no errors are reported.

Comment: This is great, thanks. I had assumed that PositiveIntegerFields validated automatically.

Comment: @Ewan It does, except when using SQLite, which drops the validators